# MS Access query to calc commission by month

Tags: ms-access, subquery

This is a long post, I hope it makes sense and I appreciate any help!

I need to set up a database in Access that will be used to calculate sales commission.  The commission % varies by month over the first year of service, after which it is constant.

I have been struggling with writing a query/subquery to handle this.

The commission rates paid by month need to be able to change over time to reflect business needs, and as the database holds historic data the right rate needs to be applied to each sale.

I have the following tables:

- Employees - EmployeeID, First Name, Last Name, StartDate
- Sales - EmployeeID, SalesDate, Amount
- Targets - MonthsOfService, CommissionRate,StartDate (i.e. when rate
  was introduced)

The Targets table contains the following for MonthsOfService, CommissionRate and StartDate

- 1,   0%,   01/01/2014
- 2,   2.5%, 01/01/2014
- 3,   5%,   01/01/2014
- 4...
- 5...
- 12, 15%, 01/01/2014 (=this rate applied to all subsequent
  months)
- 1   1%,   01/01/2015 (=new rate for month 1 applied from this date forward)
- 2   3%,   01/01/2015

What I'd like to do is create a query to calculate the Employee Months of Service for a Sale, then choose the appropriate commission rate based on the SalesDate by selecting all rates that match the Month Of Service and selecting Max date less than SalesDate.  If an employee's months of service >last month entry then the rate for last month entry needs to be used - e.g. if 12 months are defined then use month 12, if 15 months defined then use month 15.

Thanks

Comment: This will probably take a couple queries to accomplish. First you'll need to determine the commission value to use. If you're looking historically You'll need to find the Max date of the commission value the occurs before the sales date. Then use that query to match the commission values to the targets table, then add Employees and Sales which are joined.  Also, you should reconsider renaming one of your "StartDate" fields.. Having two of them makes things confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say, writing SQL in Access is not my strong suit. So I did this using three Access queries. While this may not be the most efficient way to handle this hopefully using three separate queries will explain the method behind what I'm doing a little clearer than mixing it all into one query.

Query 1: Determins the number of months for each sales, and joins it to the commission table. We do our first filter and rule out any commission changes after the sales date. This will create more records than we need, but we'll filter them later.

```
SELECT Employees.StartDate AS Emp_StartDate, Targets.StartDate AS Tar_StartDate, sales.SalesDate, Employees.EmployeeID, Targets.MonthsOfService
        FROM Targets, sales INNER JOIN Employees ON sales.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
        WHERE (((Targets.StartDate)<=[sales].[salesDate]) AND ((Targets.MonthsOfService)=IIf(DateDiff("m",[Employees].[StartDate],[sales].[SalesDate])>12,12,DateDiff("m",[Employees].[StartDate],[sales].[SalesDate]))))
```

Query 2:  Now we filter out the records.  retrieving only the max date for each sale and Commission record prior to the sales date.

```
SELECT Query1.Emp_StartDate, Max(Query1.Tar_StartDate) AS MaxOfTar_StartDate, Query1.SalesDate, Query1.EmployeeID, Query1.MonthsOfService
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Emp_StartDate, Query1.SalesDate, Query1.EmployeeID, Query1.MonthsOfService;
```

Query 3: Now we combine the results with the original tables to give the Employee with their sales data, and the most applicable commission data.

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Employees.StartDate, sales.SalesDate, sales.amount, Targets.CommissionRate
FROM ((Query2INNER JOIN Employees ON Query2.EmployeeID =   Employees.EmployeeID) INNER JOIN sales ON (Query2.SalesDate = sales.SalesDate)     AND (Employees.EmployeeID = sales.EmployeeID)) INNER JOIN Targets ON (Query2.MonthsOfService = Targets.MonthsOfService) AND (Query2.MaxOfTar_StartDate = Targets.StartDate);
```

If you were to write this in SQL it would look something like the query below.  This will not work in Access, but I just wanted to give an idea of what it would look like if done in one query in SQL

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName,
Employees.LastName,
Employees.StartDate,
Sales.SalesDate,
Sales.Amount,
Targets.CommissionRate

FROM Employees, Targets
INNER JOIN Sales
 ON Sales.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN (SELECT CommissionQuery.Emp_StartDate, 
        Max(CommissionQuery.Tar_StartDate) MaxOfTar_StartDate, 
        CommissionQuery.SalesDate, 
        CommissionQuery.EmployeeID, 
        CommissionQuery.MonthsOfService

        FROM (SELECT Employees.StartDate Emp_StartDate, 
              Targets.StartDate Tar_StartDate, 
              sales.SalesDate, 
              Employees.EmployeeID, 
              Targets.MonthsOfService
              FROM Targets, sales 
              INNER JOIN Employees 
              ON sales.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
              WHERE Targets.StartDate <= [sales].[salesDate] 
              AND Targets.MonthsOfService)=IIf(DateDiff("m",[Employees].[StartDate],[sales].[SalesDate])>12,12,DateDiff("m",[Employees].[StartDate],[sales].[SalesDate]
              ) CommissionQuery
        GROUP BY CommissionQuery.Emp_StartDate, CommissionQuery.SalesDate, CommissionQuery.EmployeeID, CommissionQuery.MonthsOfService;
        ) MaxCommission
 ON MaxCommission.SalesDate = Sales.SalesDate
 AND MaxCommission.MaxofTar_StartDate = Targets.StartDate
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough reply.I need to work through this again in more detail so that I fully understand the approach.  One initial question - whilst the commission structure is currently defined for 12 months, I would like to create a flexible solution whereby the '12' is not hardcoded in, i.e. it will always take the last 'month of service' defined in the targets table to use.  How would you amend the above to do that?

Comment: If a previous set of target rates went to 12 months, I would get into the habit of always using 12 months. It greatly simplifies the calculations. So for example if your rate schedule actually stopped at 9 months, you would still input all the way up to 12, just use the same value for the rate as 9 months. Trying to stop at 9, especially when previous rates may go further is going to cause you a lot headaches you can easily avoid.

Comment: OK, thanks I think this makes sense.  I've been through this in detail now, I can't get my head around the inner joins in query 3 (why they are all needed) and also the 'AND' part

Comment: The inner joins connect 1. the employee table with the sales table, so that you can get the user and their sales information. Since we don't actually join table Targerts, we need a way to filter for just the commission rates that we need. This is where the "AND"s come in. 2. we do an inner join on the Targets table and Query2. This limits our results to only the records in the Targets table with the applicable sales data. The Additional "AND"'s do this filter as well as 'link' the correct record back to the Employee and Sales tables.  hopefully giving the desired end result.